# legend color according to a specific field and legend label on the other field in vega lite

Tags: json, visualization, vega-lite, vega, vega-lite-api

I am creating a horizontal stack bar chart and want to add legend , but i want legend color on the basis of field are define in my data(i.e color_name) in each data element
[image: data formata]

i want legend use my color field and also show legend label on the basis of different field  i.e "occuring_event" .
how it is possible what are modification in data set require to achieve this.

i just used scale range in specs as but not look same as i want
[scale range use plz check in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoZACcA1gH0kUNCAByAJjFiAjI4DMAQUUg2UKAZTGlkySzhSWUw7AGJHAAIAJSRZc19tXTg0VwAGJSg2QTZTS1kkBCz0YTIsJkyQAF8FEyQLa1t0Jxd3b19-QODQ8Mjo9BjXJJS0pQy9bPzC4tLyypA6uaaWtps7LrdPHyV+oJCwiLgo2Ink1PSdOdRXBaKSsoq7dazNkDMrHc7XAB2YFiXpHAInIbnS5ja5TO71R5iZ5LN6rGIAMSx2MazR+rT+HQcQJBYL8EMGZxGsQSN2mIFmlVyKNeKzsZFMcAuuK2hN2JMBYgAHICycdKcMLqMQDEPJNbjN7ky8iACi9lu90JzlDz8dsifYBcLRYdyQNTpKYTKACzy+mM7IqtWotnoACecEERQA7o0ALpNPVpTQgTBunCrJitXEgC4FZSnNCgAAeSZASDIHL4mFWEAYCF8ADMaJ6degHUowxG7ABHBgpTB0NQ0Ui+RuYQSrRkGQNutPF0t2X7tNvh1ayNgIEI6GPO0z9kuCMtmyFUqW+aA6SqgUwpMjbkADpd2Ocar4NC8NIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example in the docs you can use as a guide:

https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/scale.html#example-setting-color-range-based-on-a-field

[image]

Comment: it is not working as i need u can check it here

Comment: It isn't working because your data is contradictory. You are saying #1 Rank should be blue and also #FFFFFF - it needs to be one or the other.